# Onclick link to save multiple data without refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

With this code I can see empty data saving into my db once I click on the link button. But i need to the GET's data in my database. Any solution to this.

```
<a href="?id=1&pid=238874" id="day" onclick="this.form.submit();><button type="button" class="label label-danger" >Select</button></a>

<script>
$('#day').click(function(e) 
       {
         e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
               type: 'post',
               url: "index.php",
               data: $("select.day").serialize(),
           });
            return false;
       });
</script>
```

For PHP Code to save data

```
<?php
$a = $_GET['id'];
$b = $_GET['pid'];
// query
$sql = "INSERT INTO hos_patient(reg_id,pid) VALUES ('$a','$b')";
mysqli_query($db, $sql); 
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you found solution? Please vote for the answer(s) that helps you.

Comment: No solution yet, I have tried all solution provided and its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="?id=1&pid=238874" class="login_form_1"><button type="button" class="label label-danger" >Select</button></a>

<script>
 $(function () {
    $('.login_form_1').on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'show.php?id=22&pid=33',
            data: $('.login_form_1').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
              $('div.logerrors').html(data);
            }
          });
    });
  });
</script>
```

For PHP output

```
<?php
$a = $_GET['id'];
$b = $_GET['pid'];
// query
$sql = "INSERT INTO hos_patient(reg_id,pid) VALUES ('$a','$b')";
mysqli_query($db, $sql); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You specified using `POST` in your ajax function. But then you try to get the data by `GET` in your PHP-Script. I'd suggest you just use `POST` for this.

Alter your PHP-Script to use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`

Comment: By the way.. your code is very confusing. You try to make a `GET` request on your link whilst trying to submit some kind of form and then you got an ajax request where I have no idea how you submit that one.

Comment: `<a href="?id=1&pid=238874" id="day" onclick="this.form.submit();><button type="button" class="label label-danger" >Select</button></a>` id="day" miss out. I have change it to **POST** not working yet

Comment: Have you checked the output of `$("select.day").serialize()`. Will this return any data at all?

Comment: No... I have use some values to serialize it. My aim is to get those `id=1&pid=238874` on a click

Answer (score 1):

Try with this :

```
...
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "index.php?id=1&pid=238874",
    data: $("select.day").serialize(),
});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this in script file and in PHP file use below code**

```
<script>
$('#day').click(function(e) 
       {
         e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
               type: 'post',
               url: "index.php?id=1&pid=238874",
               data: $("select.day").serialize(),
           });
            return false;
       });
</script>


    <?php
    $a = $_POST['id'];
    $b = $_POST['pid'];
    // query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO hos_patient(reg_id,pid) VALUES ('$a','$b')";
    mysqli_query($db, $sql); 
    ?>
```